# "google not defined" error in maps api in ejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, ejs

Why am I getting the error that 'google is not defined' when using the Maps API? I tried removing the async in the script tag like in some other posts, but that didn't work either. I am still learning the syntax of EJS, so maybe it's something regarding that.

It is pointing at the line where the second for loop starts to make markers.

```
 <body>
    <% console.log(values)%>
        <% for (i=0; i<values.length; i++) { %>
            <% var o = JSON.parse(values[i])%>
            <% var lat = o.latitude%>
            <% var long = o.longitude%>
            <% var desc = o.description%>
            <% var name = o.name%>
            <li><%=o.latitude%></li>
        <% } %>

    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>
      function initMap() {
         var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 10,
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(39.952335, -75.163789)
        }); 

         <% for (i=0; i<values.length; i++) { 
                 var o = JSON.parse(values[i]) 
                 var lat = o.latitude 
                 var long = o.longitude 
                 var desc = o.description 
                 var name = o.name 

                 var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat,long),
                    map: map
                 });
            }
        %>
      }
    </script>
    <script
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=(xxxx)&callback=initMap">
    </script>
```

Comment: Add your script before calling the API

Comment: Suresh, isn't that how it is right now? Not sure which script you're referring to.

Comment: We can see your API key... not your real one I hope

Comment: Just edited that.. thanks! still not sure about this order problem though :(

Comment: Shift the line that starts `<script src = etc>` to above your function

Comment: I just put my API script tag right beneath the div id = map line but still getting the same error?

Comment: Have you tried with `async defer` attributes just like in the official documentation of Google Maps API: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key?